# Is it a function when one output isn't used?

Tags: functions

I have a very basic question. From what I have learned it is not a function when one of the outputs from a ordered set isn't used. Is this correct?

I am trying to determine if this relation is a function on the set {a,b,c,d}:

[image: arrow diagram]

What I find based on what I have learned is that this is not a function because C has no output?

Comment: What is your definition of a function?  In mathematics, it is very important to understand what the definitions are saying.  Something like this is a good test for how well one understands a definition.

Comment: actually you could interpret this as a function $\{A,B,D\} \to \mathrm{map}(\{C\} , \{A,B,C,D \})$

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, its only a partial function. Such functions are considered, e.g., in computability theory.

A function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ assigns to each $x\in X$ exactly one $y\in Y$, written $y=f(x)$. Here the element $C$ has no image.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a function**.

The definition of a function is that a relation from a set of inputs to a set of possible outputs where each input is related to exactly one output.

Since all the inputs of the set does not have all the inputs to the other set, i.e. *for the first set, C does not have any input and for the second set, A & C* are not mapped to any input of the first set.  Therefore, it is not a function but only a relation.